# RPI access point and how to share the internet with connected devices

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, debian, internet, access-point

I want to share the Internet from my USB modem stick on my raspberry pi to other devices by turning my pi into a WiFi access point. I am using a pi 3 model B+ running raspbian stretch and I am able to create the access point and other devices are able to connect to it. I used wvdial to establish an internet connection on my pi and it shows that it is indeed connected to the internet however I can not open a single website on the connected devices nor can I open a website on my browser on the pi. Anytime I try to ping google on the pi it shows 
`ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known`
How can I get the internet working on the pi and share that same internet with the connected devices

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: When you have established an internet connection then please [edit your question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/93787/edit) and insert the output of these commands: `ip addr, ip route, cat /etc/resolv.conf`. And please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.